# Error in debugging php project in visual studio 2015

Tags: php, visual-studio

I am Creating a **PHP** project in visual studio 2015 with php tools for Visual Studio, But facing an error saying  `You Environment is missing php5.6 with debugging extensions`
[image]

when i click ok, it opens a download window Console, here i am facing another Error which is:
[image]

the question is: Why am I facing these Error? and How can i resolve these Errors? **Thanks!**

Comment: Read the red text in your console window...

Comment: I have read, but i am not getting it what it means

Comment: It clearly states that the installation of PHP failed. You can try a manual installation directly from php.net for your IIS setup.

Comment: I have already installed php 7.4 for visual studio 2015, still it was showing this error, that is why i posted it here